# How to choose the secondary monitor in Lightroom/Windows

Tags: lightroom, monitors, windows-7, lightroom-6

I'm using Lightroom in Windows 7, and I have 3 screens.

From left to right:
[Screen1:Television(not good at all for photography)] - [Screen2] - [Screen3]

I do work on the right screen and have photo preview on the right. But I have just learned from some specialist that my slight back problems come from turning my head to the right too often. I would like to use my middle screen as my work screen. I cannot change the screens positions, I cannot switch the TV and the right screen. I don't want to break the screens matching borders (when mouse goes from one to the other). And anyway, Lightroom is not the only application on my computer so that kind of requirements would feel invasive.

Whatever I do lightroom will always display the secondary preview on the first screen on the left of the screen I'm working on. Which means:

If Screen 3 is main, Screen 2 is secondary.

If Screen 2 is main, Screen 1 is secondary

If Screen 1 is main, Screen 3 is secondary.

What I want is to use Screen 2/Middle as main and Screen 3/Right as secondary preview.

I have already tried changing windows Screen Resolution preferences, and I have tried switching cables at the computer. Yet, Lightroom won't change its logic.

Is there a solution ? Thank you.

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one with this dumb problem. It's times like these that makes me want to switch since it's an easy fix.

Answer (score 2):

This has long been a problem in LR, and unfortunately it looks like Adobe has no interest in fixing it, as it has persisted from LR4 thru to LR CC.  You may find one of the tips listed in this long thread helpful:

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/725985

Answer (score 1):

This setup worked for me. I set monitor #3 as my main display (select monitor #3 and check the box under the "Multiple Displays" section to "make this my main display"). Then drag monitor #1 below monitor #2. Now the primary Lightroom window is displayed on monitor #3 and the secondary LR window is displayed on monitor #2. The only catch, and it's a very tiny catch, is that to get to monitor #1, you'll move your mouse DOWN to monitor #1 instead of directly to the right, from monitor #2, just as shown in the diagram below, because your monitors are no longer configured in a straight line. Hope this helps.

[image: Display settings in windows]

[image: Lightroom setup]